# Android getting data out of listview

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I'm at the moment programming an APP with an listview which is filled with data from an SQLite Table like this:

```
public void printDatabase(){
    Cursor c = handler.getAllRows();
    String[] fieldNames = new String[] {DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_ID, DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_NAME, DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_SURNAME, DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_COST};
    int[] toView = new int[] {R.id.item_worker_id, R.id.item_worker_name, R.id.item_worker_surname, R.id.item_worker_cost};
    SimpleCursorAdapter cAdapter;
    cAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(getBaseContext(), R.layout.worker_items, c, fieldNames, toView, 0);
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.worker_listView);
    list.setAdapter(cAdapter);
}
```

Now I'd like to get the data from the listview of an item by clicking the item. I've searched everywhere to find a solution for this and found this:

```
class ItemListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Object o = list.getItemAtPosition(i);
        String s = list.toString();
    }
}
```

But all I get from this is the reference to the cursor I've used for filling the listview. What do I need to get the data from the listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are half way to your solution already.

```
Cursor itemCursor = (Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(i);
```

This returns you a cursor pointing to the row that is clicked. You can get the data out of it like:

```
class ItemListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Cursor itemCursor = (Cursor) list.getItemAtPosition(i);

        String workerId = itemCursor.getString(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler. COLUMN_WORKER_ID));
        String workerName = itemCursor.getString(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_NAME));
        String workerSurname = itemCursor.getString(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_SURNAME));
        String workerCost = itemCursor.getString(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler.COLUMN_WORKER_COST));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Make the cursor global ;

```
Cursor cursor ;
```

In your OnItemClick

```
class ItemListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
     cursor.moveToPosition(position);
     String Id = cursor.getString(itemCursor.getColumnIndex(DBHandler. COLUMN_WORKER_ID));
 }

}
```

Comment: Oh God why a global variable?

Comment: Because it is less expensive than casting sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ItemListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener{

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_content);
        String text = textView.getText().toString(); 
        //Log.d("Choosen: " + text);
}}
```